# travis builds failing due to rstan compilation issues

Tags: r, travis-ci, rstan

My package builds on Linux are failing with the following compilation error for `rstan` package:

```r
lto-wrapper: fatal error: make returned 2 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rstan.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rstan’
```

How can I modify my `travis.yaml` to successfully install `rstan` on Travis?

Build log:
https://travis-ci.org/IndrajeetPatil/statsExpressions/builds/638404778?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification

Travis yaml:
https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/statsExpressions/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: I would try with the `-flto=2` flag in travis.yaml .

Comment: @BenGoodrich How can I add multiple flags? `MAKEFLAGS="-j 2 && -flto 2"`?

Comment: There is a line that says `echo "CXX14 = g++-7 -fPIC -flto=2" >> ~/.R/Makevars`, which you can change to whatever you want, but I would suggest removing the `-flto=2` if that is causing problems. You can set the `MAKEVARS` environmental variable elsewhere.

Comment: I tried after removing `-flto=2`, but the same issue persists.

Comment: You still have `/usr/bin/ld: lto-wrapper failed` without using LTO?

Comment: No, it's a different error now: `make: *** [chains.o] Error 1` (log: https://travis-ci.org/IndrajeetPatil/statsExpressions/jobs/638635866?utm_medium=notification&utm_source=github_status)

Comment: OK. That syntax should work and I believe does work outside of Travis. But I have not been able to get much value out of Travis for Stan-related packages.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion anyway. I can also confirm that other packages that rely on `rstan` are also facing the same issue: https://travis-ci.org/danheck/metaBMA/builds/612303943

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying out many many different permutations and combinations, I finally got Travis builds to succeed, not only by compiling `rstan` properly but also installing other packages that need compilation so that the log doesn't exceed maximum limit or time out.

Here is the new `yaml` file for anyone who may run into a similar issue in the future: 
https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/statsExpressions/blob/master/.travis.yml